# How to pass generic list class as an argument to generic method in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I want to have a method which would return required type of objects extracted from a map.
Here is an example

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("ids", Arrays.asList(5,345,45645)); 
map.put("id", 325); 

<T> T get(String arg, Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) map.get(arg);
}
```

Then, for example, Integer can be gotten with this code

```
Integer id = get("id", Integer.class);
```

But when I'm trying to get a list of objects in these ways

```
List<Integer> ids = get("ids", new ArrayList<Integer>().getClass());
List<Integer> ids = get("id", List.class);
```

Intellij IDEA warns: `Unchecked assignment: 'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>'`

I expected something like `List<Integer>.class` (by analogy to `Integer.class`, `Boolean.class` etc...) what would be used as

```
List<Integer> ids = get("ids", List<Integer>.class`)
```

but this is not compiled.

So is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need the `Class` parameter.

```
<T> T unsafeGet(String arg) {
    return (T) map.get(arg);
}
```

I renamed the method, because you're **throwing away all compiler type-checking**.

These two lines compile, but fail at runtime:

```
Integer ids = unsafeGet("ids"); // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
Element id = unsafeGet("id");   // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element
```